# Is there a way to use default in object construction with jq?

Tags: json, jq, default-value

I want to filter and assign a value from array based on a condition, and use default in case if array does not have the matched object.

Here is a sample object:

```
{
    "array" : [
            {   
                "id": "A",
                "conversations": [   
                    {
                    "conversation": "1",
                    "type": "good"
                    },
                    {
                    "conversation": "2", 
                    "type": "bad"
                    }
                ]

            },
            {   
                "id": "B",
                "conversations": [   
                    {
                    "conversation": "3",
                    "type": "good"
                    },
                    {
                    "conversation": "4", 
                    "type": "bad"
                    }
                ]

            },
            {   
                "id": "C",
                "conversations": [   
                    {
                    "conversation": "5",
                    "type": "bad"
                    },
                    {
                    "conversation": "6", 
                    "type": "bad"
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]
}
```

Required output:

```
{
  "id": "A",
  "goodConversation": "1"
}
{
  "id": "B",
  "goodConversation": "3"
},
{
  "id": "C",
  "goodConversation": null
}
```

echo of my input:

```
echo '{"array":[{"id":"A","conversations":[{"conversation":"1","type":"good"},{"conversation":"2","type":"bad"}]},{"id":"B","conversations":[{"conversation":"3","type":"good"},{"conversation":"4","type":"bad"}]},{"id":"C","conversations":[{"conversation":"5","type":"bad"},{"conversation":"6","type":"bad"}]}]}'
```

I tried running following `jq`

```
jq '.array[] | {id, "goodConversation": .conversations[] | select(.type == "good") | .conversation}'
```

Actual output:

```
{
  "id": "A",
  "goodConversation": "1"
}
{
  "id": "B",
  "goodConversation": "3"
}
```

since the object with id: "C" does not have any good conversation the whole object gets filtered out. Is there a way to create the output object which contains "C" with `null` as value?

**Clarification**:

- "conversations" will have at most one good conversation.
- I am using jq 1.5

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for pointing this out, it is expected to have only one good conversation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to provide a default value is often to use the `//` "alternative" operator.  Building on the foundations you've laid, you could write:

```
.array[]
| {id, 
   "goodConversation": 
     ((.conversations[]
      | select(.type == "good")
      | .conversation) // null) }
```

If there is more than one "good" conversation, however, this may not be exactly what you want.  If it's not, then consider using `first`, e.g.:

```
.array[]
| {id,
   "goodConversation":
     ( first(.conversations[]
             | select(.type == "good")
             | .conversation) // null)}
```

Comment: my bad i did not add `// null` which I thought was a comment due to code markdown, @peak & @oguzismail